# How to run PowerShell scripts via automation without running into Host issues

Tags: powershell, automation, hosting, powershell-2.0

I'm looking to run some powershell scripts via automation. Something like:

```
IList errors;
Collection<PSObject> res = null;
using (RunspaceInvoke rsi = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
    try
    {
        res = rsi.Invoke(commandline, null, out errors);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LastErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(LastErrorMessage);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

the problem I'm facing is that if my script uses cmdlets such as `write-host` the above throws an `System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException` -

> Cannot invoke this function because
>   the current host does not implement
>   it.

What are some good options for getting around this problem?

Comment: Scott, I'm facing the same problem. Could you provide some guidance or code on how you did the implementation?

Comment: Ok, found the answer myself: Just inherit PSHost, PSHostUserInterface and PSHostRawUserInterface and have the methods do nothing/return null. To trace what would normally happen, messages/text that would otherwise be printed at the cmd-line could be logged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to create a write-host function and inject that into your runspace.  The function will take precedence over a cmdlet with the same name.  In this function, you could do nothing or perhaps use [console]::writeline() if your app is a console app, or if your app is a GUI app, inject some object into the PowerShell session that the function can write the output to (look at Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable).

Another (bit more complicated) option is to implement the [PowerShell hosting interfaces in your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshost(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I went with the hosting interfaces approach. Too bad there's not a default NonInteractive UI for hosting.