# Running PowerShell through C# pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I am writing PS script that will be integrated with the C# based Windows Form Application. This is what I have tried/done already:

1. I am able to run PS scripts through the runspace and pipeline, however i encounter the error while I am trying to run the script that uses functions, saying: **" Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it."**
2. I have researched the problem and I have found very few people who had encoutered similar problem, however one of the solutions underlined that I need to use (add) the following $ConfirmPreference = "None", ,-Confirm:$false, -Force
3. However when I tried that the following error message appeared: **" Missing expression after unary operator '-'. "** You can see that I have tried to concatenate the strings by assigning them to the variables, but that did not help. I do not have any idea how to solve it, has anyone got any ideas? Any help will be much appreciated.

   ```
      // create Powershell runspace
      Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
      // open it
      runspace.Open();

      // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
      Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

      //allow the functions to be exec
      string sa = "$ConfirmPreference = \"None\" ";
      string se = " -Confirm:$false -Force";
      string s = sa +scriptText + se;
      pipeline.Commands.AddScript(s);
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Confirm:$false -Force` are meant to be function parameters, they don't exist on their own.

```
Do-Something -param1 'foo' -Confirm:$false -Force
```

But even if you modify every function call with these parameters, it probably won't solve all of your issues.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656610/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-via-automation-without-running-into-host-issues) for more options.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help, you have clarified a lot.

Answer (score -1):

OK, there is an Object coming with PowerShell called CommonParameters ([MSDN: System.Management.Automation.Internal.CommonParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.internal.commonparameters%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Parameters which are meant can be seen here: [MSDN: Common Parameter Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd901844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And as far as I know, is the variable `$ConfirmPreference` set to `None` you don't need to set `Confirm` to `false` for every `Command` you are calling. That's implicitly...

And you also must set this variable one time after creating `Runspace` or before calling your first `Command`, and not with each `Command` or `Script`.

And you can also set this variable like this:

```
runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ConfirmPreference", "none");
```